# Pentaho kettle transforming xml using xslt file java

Tags: xml, xslt, pentaho, kettle

I want to write kettle step in  Java  that takes input XML and XSLT file and returns output the transformed XML.

How do I do this? I have no idea from where to begin and there is not enough documentation to Java and Pentaho in the web.

Comment: In the recent past, you have asked several broad questions where you explicitly state that you "have no idea where to start". If so, Stackoverflow is not the place for your question. If you have no idea about Java, XSLT, XML, Pentaho and Kettle I suggest you start by reading a book or tutorial.

Comment: Suggest that you revise the title to "Pentaho Kettle transforming XML file using XSLT" since the important nuance is that this technique works against an XML file whereas the inbuilt Pentaho XSLT support only works for an XML field/variable.

Answer (score 2):

I Found the answer code for transforming xml using xslt in kettle java :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

private int infilenameIndex;
private int xsltfilenameIndex;
private int outfilenameIndex;


public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException {
  Object[] r=getRow();
  if (r==null) {
    setOutputDone();
    return false;
  }


  if (first == false) {
     infilenameIndex = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(getParameter("infilename"));
     if (infilenameIndex < 0) {
         throw new KettleException("Field not found in the input row, check parameter 'infilename'!");
     }
     xsltfilenameIndex = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(getParameter("xsltfilename"));
     if (xsltfilenameIndex < 0) {
         throw new KettleException("Field not found in the input row, check parameter 'xsltfilename'!");
     }
     outfilenameIndex = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(getParameter("outfilename"));
     if (outfilenameIndex < 0) {
         throw new KettleException("Field not found in the input row, check parameter 'outfilename'!");
     }

     first=false;
  }

  String infilename = get(Fields.In, "infilename").getString(r);
  String xsltfilename = get(Fields.In, "xsltfilename").getString(r);
  String outfilename = get(Fields.In, "outfilename").getString(r);

  Object[] outputRowData = RowDataUtil.resizeArray(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
  int outputIndex = getInputRowMeta().size();

  transform(infilename, xsltfilename, outfilename);


  putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRowData);

  return true;
}
public void transform(String infilename, String xsltfilename, String outfilename) throws KettleException {

    javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource inss = null;
    javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource xsltss = null;
    javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult outss = null;

    logBasic("");
    logBasic("Transformerar " +  infilename + " med " + xsltfilename + " till " + outfilename );
    logBasic("");

    try {
       inss = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(infilename);
    }     
    catch (Exception e) {
       logError("Infil saknas " +  infilename);
       throw new KettleException(e);
    }

    try {
       xsltss = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xsltfilename);
    }     
    catch (Exception e) {
       logError("Xsltfil saknas " +  xsltfilename);
       throw new KettleException(e);
    }

    try {
       outss = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(outfilename);
    }     
    catch (Exception e) {
       logError("Outfil saknas " +  outfilename);
       throw new KettleException(e);
    }

    try {       
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        // Set the TransformerFactory to the SAXON implementation.
        //tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();

        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltss);

        // Do the transfromtation
        transformer.transform(inss, outss);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       throw new KettleException(e);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: If you found that on the web you should provide the link out of politeness.  However I don't really understand why you don't just use the inbuilt "XSL Transformation" step.

Answer (score 0):

I can see how this would be preferable for large XML files as it allows for file/stream-based processing of the XML instead of holding the entire XML in a Pentaho variable.  I maxed out my JVM heap due to a large generated XML dataset so I'm hopeful this code--or a variant--might allow me to not keep the full XML in memory... will report back!

Here's my refactoring/consolidation of the example code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException {
    Object[] row = getRow();
    if (row == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }
    String infilename = getStringField(row, "infilename");
    String xsltfilename = getStringField(row, "xsltfilename");
    String outfilename = getStringField(row, "outfilename");
    Object[] outputRowData = RowDataUtil.resizeArray(row, data.outputRowMeta.size());
    doXSLT(infilename, xsltfilename, outfilename);
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRowData);
    return true;
}

private String getStringField(Object[] row, String paramName) throws KettleException {
    String value = get(Fields.In, paramName).getString(row);
    if(value == null || "".equals(value)) {
        throw new KettleException("XSLT setting '" + paramName + "' not found in input row");
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

public void doXSLT(String infilename, String xsltfilename, String outfilename) throws KettleException {
    logBasic("");
    logBasic("Transforming XML file '" +  infilename + "' with XSLT '" + xsltfilename + "' and target file '" + outfilename + "'" );
    logBasic("");
    try {
        StreamSource inss = new StreamSource("file:///"+infilename);
        StreamSource xsltss = new StreamSource("file:///"+xsltfilename);
        StreamResult outss = new StreamResult("file:///"+outfilename);
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        // Set the TransformerFactory to the SAXON implementation.
        //tFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltss);
        transformer.transform(inss, outss);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logError("Error attempting XSLT: " +  e);
        throw new KettleException(e);
    }
    return;
}
```